# How to iterate over every second number

Tags: loops, rust

Reading the docs, I noticed a sentence saying: "Rust doesn't have a *C style* for loop.". So, I wonder, how can I make a loop equivalent to `for(i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) { }`?

The ways I can think of are something like:

```
for i in 0..10 {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
let i = 0;
loop {
    if i < 10 {
        //Do stuff
        i += 2;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way, especially since it's really verbose. Is there a *better way*? I'm guessing it would be with *iterators*, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is now implemented in std with the [step_by function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by)

```
for i in (0..10).step_by(2) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's [`std::iter::range_step`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/fn.range_step.html) right now, but it's marked as unstable with the message "likely to be replaced by range notation and adapters".

```
fn main() {
    for i in std::iter::range_step(0, 10, 2) {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

prints

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: Note: @ker presented the alternative using `itertools` to implement on top of the range notation.

Answer (score 4):

the [itertools crate](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) offers what you want for abitrary iterators. The [step function](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.step) creates an iterator that skips `n-1` elements after each iteration.

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let mut it = (0..10).step(2);
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(0));
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(2));
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(4));
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(6));
assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(8));
assert_eq!(it.next(), None);
```