# Is there a way to get every n * i element of a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, linear-algebra

Is there any clever way to get every `n * i` element of a vector? I have this vector:

```rust
let example = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I want every third value of this vector, so the output will be:

```rust
let result = vec![3, 6, 9];
```

I know that I can achieve this with a for loop:

```rust
let mut result: Vec<i32> = vec![];
let offset = 3;
for (index, value) in example.iter().enumerate() {
    if (index + 1) % offset == 0 {
        result.push(value.clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `n` and `i` in the question title? And you seem to have a solution, so what exactly is your question? If there is anything about your solution that you don't like, please let us know what it is, so we understand what problem to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To iterate over every **n**th element, use [`.step_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by). However, using that starts at the initial value, you'll need to chain [`.skip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) as well. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8dc3e1f2607fe68d13f2c20a44c05e27):

```
let example = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let n = 3;
let result: Vec<_> = example.iter().skip(n-1).step_by(n).copied().collect();
println!("{:?}", result);
```

```
[3, 6, 9]
```

See also:

- [Iterator that returns each Nth value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798026/iterator-that-returns-each-nth-value)
- [How to iterate over every second number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669607/how-to-iterate-over-every-second-number)

Comment: That looks so clean :D. Thank you @kmdreko